# pig Unknown method getNewApplication error

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying in pig to:
REGISTER '/home/hduser/pig-0.11.1/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar'
xml = load 'hdfs:///user/hduser/BB8100/BB8100.html' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('td') as(doc:chararray); 
value = foreach xml GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(doc,'(.*)'))  AS td:chararray;
dump value

and I get:

java.io.IOException: Unknown method getNewApplication called on interface org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ClientRMProtocol$ClientRMProtocolService$BlockingInterface protocol.

HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
0.23.1  0.11.2-SNAPSHOT hduser  2014-03-31 22:07:15 2014-03-31 22:07:24 UNKNOWN

Any help is much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

cd /home/hduser/pig-0.11.1/contrib/piggybank/java

ant clean jar -Dhadoopversion=23 -Dmr1.test=mr1 (I had done this for Pig before getting the error).